# Does SimpleCursorAdapter run on UI thread

Tags: java, android

In the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D,%20int%29) it's mentioned that

```
SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to)
```

is **discouraged**, as it results in Cursor queries being performed **on the application's UI thread** ..

But nothing has been mentioned about the below constructor

```
SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags)
```

So doesSimpleCursorAdapter with 2nd constructor run on UI thread

Comment: Yes you have to run it on UI thread

Comment: @PiyushGupta am asking whether it would run on a background thread or UI thread

Comment: depends on the `int flags` part. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093380/what-to-set-cursoradaptercontext-context-cursor-c-int-flags-to-in-order-to-m (use `0` and it won't. At least when you don't have problems with your cursor window)

Comment: @zapl so with 0 flag it won't run on UI thread but on a background thread

Answer (score -1):

```
all Adapters works on UI Thread in android . if you wants to use from Non UI Thread use this 

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

@Override
        public void run() {
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
});
or simply post a runnable to the UI thread:

view.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

});

Comment: Errr... no. That would be a way to create an Adapter within a background thread and set it in the ui thread. And that is not going to give you any benefit.